# How can I find out how an annotation is implemented?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

I want to see how **Lock** annotation is implemented in spring-data-jpa.
I believe they use aop-alliance and intercept the annotationed methods and add some logic but I have no idea where to look for the implementation?

```
 // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.data/spring-data-jpa
implementation group: 'org.springframework.data', name: 'spring-data-jpa', version: '2.7.1'
```

[image: Lock annotation]

Comment: They do and they don't. The AOP part is just for routing the call to the `SimpleJpaRepository`. The annotation is detected at runtime and added to the metadata of the method execution.

Comment: You probably should look for places that check whether a class or method has that annotation, rather than the annotation itself.

Comment: I understand, but do you have any idea where to find how it is implemented? I don't want to see the documentation, I want to see the actual code implementation for Lock. ( I added the print screen to clarify what annotation I'm talking about)

Comment: @Opri what I mean is `Lock` itself does nothing. It doesn't have an implementation. There are pieces of *other* code in the framework that check whether a class or method is annotated with `Lock` and *they* do something with it.

Comment: You could try cloning the repo, opening your IDE, and using its "Find Usages" feature. That may help, depending on how good the IDE is and the organization of the source code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Lock` is an annotation and as such doesn't have any code directly attached to  it.

The code "implementing it" will have to find the annotation usages and the work with that information. In order to find those places you'll search for usages of that annotation in your source code. With `Lock` this should lead you to [this code snippet](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/blob/b57eb85a230d3a05e45276052ef62b1249e5a0e6/spring-data-jpa/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/query/JpaQueryMethod.java#L118):

```java
this.lockModeType = Lazy
                .of(() -> (LockModeType) Optional.ofNullable(AnnotatedElementUtils.findMergedAnnotation(method, Lock.class)) //
                        .map(AnnotationUtils::getValue) //
                        .orElse(null));
```

From there you can follow it through the code.